# Extract all occurrences of characters that differ between two strings

Tags: r, string, character

I have used `adist` to calculate the number of characters that differ between two strings:

```
a <- "#IvoryCoast TENNIS US OPEN Clément «Un beau combat» entre Simon et Cilic"
b <- "Clément «Un beau combat» entre Simon et Cilic"
adist(a,b) # result 27
```

Now I would like to extract *all the occurrences* of those characters that differ. In my example, I would like to get the string `"#IvoryCoast TENNIS US OPEN "`.

I tried and used:

```
paste(Reduce(setdiff, strsplit(c(a, b), split = "")), collapse = "")
```

But the obtained result is not what I expected!

```
#IvysTENOP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do, based on the `paste/reduce` solution:

```
paste(Reduce(setdiff, strsplit(c(a, b), split = " ")), collapse = " ")
#[1] "#IvoryCoast TENNIS US OPEN"
```

Or, if you want to get separated items, with `setdiff` and `strsplit`:

```
setdiff(strsplit(a," ")[[1]],strsplit(b," ")[[1]])
#[1] "#IvoryCoast" "TENNIS"      "US"          "OPEN"
```

Answer (score 4):

For this case, you could use gsub.

```
> a <- "#IvoryCoast TENNIS US OPEN Clément «Un beau combat» entre Simon et Cilic"
> b <- "Clément «Un beau combat» entre Simon et Cilic"
> gsub(b, "", a)
[1] "#IvoryCoast TENNIS US OPEN "
```